# AngularJS Directive

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I want to do dynamic modal.  Is there a shorter way?  Am I doing it right?

```
angular.module('vidyotorModal', [])
    .directive('vidyotorModal', ['$document', '$compile', function ($document, $compile) {
        return{
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $scope.closeModal = function () {
                    templateModal.remove();
                };
                callbackClick = function () {
                    var $body = $document.find('body');
                    var modal_html = '<div id="modal-box-bg" ng-click="closeModal()"></div>' +
                        '<div id="modal-box">' +
                        '<div class="inner">' +
                        '<i class="fa fa-times-circle close-btn" ng-click="closeModal()"></i>' +
                        '<div class="content">' +
                        document.getElementById('register').innerHTML +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>';
                    templateModal = $compile(modal_html)($scope);
                    $body.append(templateModal);
                };
                $element.bind('click', callbackClick)
            }
        }
    }]);
```

Comment: I'd prefer to use service for modal dialogs, like I did here https://github.com/SET001/angularjs_test_3_modal_window/blob/master/coffee/services/test-modal.coffee

Comment: You could simply add a div after your body with a ng-include directive. Now you only need to set/unset the src based on some service/ broadcasted event.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is manually recreating HTML, which is an anti-pattern. The Angular way is to supply separately HTML template and its data scope object.